# Shutdown button configured as startup, i can't access ubuntu

Tags: shutdown, 22.04, startup, dock, button

I'm pretty new. I've been a bit stupid: after installing the shutdown button from a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBNPm0fa4Do), I have configured it as startup, and now every time I turn on the computer it shuts down when Ubuntu loads (22.04.1 LTS). What I can do?
I can't access ubuntu...

Comment: Upvoted your question as it gave me a good laugh :) Putting a program that automatically shuts down your computer into autostart is a really crazy idea :)

Comment: The worst thing is that I thought about it: what happens if I do...

Answer (score 3):

Boot into rescue mode and delete that file.

1. At startup, you see the Grub menu. From that, quickly select `Advanced Options`.
2. Select the line that looks like `Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.15.0-46-generic (recovery mode)`
3. After a little while, another menu is presented. From this, choose `Drop to root shell prompt`.
4. Change to your home directory: `cd /home/[username]/`. Replace `[username]` with your actual user name.
5. Delete the file: `rm .local/share/applications/Power_off.desktop` (I think that was the correct name of the file. If not, change to the directory with `cd .local/share/applications` and do an `ls` to find out the correct name.)
6. Enter `reboot` and your system should start up normally.

Comment: I have followed the steps and to my surprise there have been no errors, but the computer continues to shut down.
I think by setting it as startup, the 'Power_off.desktop' commands have been copied into some file. It can be?
Thanks for the quick response, It is awesome!

Comment: That may be, but these commands just undo exactly what the procedure in the video created.

Comment: After the tutorial, I have configured it as startup, and that is when the problem has arisen.
Afterwards, I have created a boot disk, to try to make a backup, but I have not succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution.
File 'Power_off.desktop' was copied to '.config/autostart/'
Therefore, I have gone into root, in the mentioned folder, and used this command to remove it: sudo rm Power_off.desktop

Thank you for all.

Step by step:

Power on the computer

Esc

Choose Advanced options for Ubuntu

Choose Ubuntu ... (recovery mode)

Choose root

Enter

CD home/[name]/

CD .config

CD autostart

sudo rm Power_off.desktop

reboot